# how to stop url manupulation in rails app with devise gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

i am using devise gem to handle user. users has one_to_many association with projects. and there is multiple user each user has their own dashboard but still user are able to manipulate project_id in url and able to see other users project and also able to edit delete that. how can i stop that?

user redirection after login (project#index) -

project_controller.rb

```
def index
    @projects = current_user.projects.all.order("created_at DESC").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 15)
  end

  def show

    @project = Project.includes(stages: {tasks:}).find(params[:id])
    @stages = @project.stages
  end

  def new
    @project = current_user.projects.build
  end

  def create
    @project = current_user.projects.build(project_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to projects_url, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `current_user.projects` scope in `show` action:

```
def show
  @project = current_user.projects.includes(stages: :tasks).find(params[:id])
end
```

This way, if you edit URL and put ID belonging to another user, you'll get `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`, which is handled as 404 error by Rails by default.

Of course, you can use this approach to secure `edit`, `update` and `destroy` actions as well.